# build array or collection of records from string array and regex

Tags: arrays, collections, f#

I've a regular expression that can extract values from each of the following item in strings array.

Regex string format ->  **/guid/type/name;version**

```
/(([a-f0-9]+\-)+[a-f0-9]+)\/(.*?)\/(.*?);version=(\d*)/
```

JSON response array of entities

```
[
{
    "data": "/publication/a40a5e5c-98b3-45ae-d6a3-924b31d8712a/article/test;version=1521246543034"
}, 
{
    "data": "/publication/a40a5e5c-98b3-45ae-d6a3-924b31d8712a/book/test2;version=1520623346891"
}, 
{
    "data": "/publication/a40a5e5c-98b3-45ae-d6a3-924b31d8712a/catalog/test3;version=1520623346833"
}
]
```

**Code**

```
type Entity {
    guid: string
    ``type``: string
    name: string
    version: string
}

type List = {
    Href: string
}

let matchEntity (m: Match) =
     {guid = m.Groups.[1].Value; ``type``= m.Groups.[3].Value; name = m.Groups.[4].Value; version = m.Groups.[5].Value}


let iterate (list : List[]) : string =
    let regex = new Regex("(([a-f0-9]+\-)+[a-f0-9]+)\/(.*?)\/(.*?);version=(\d*)")
    list |> Array.iter (fun data -> data.Href |> (regex.Match >> matchEntity))
```

**Problem:**

> `matchEntity` is complaining type mismatch expecting match -> unit but given a match -> Entity

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to escape your `type` field, because it's a reserved keyword:

```
type Entity = {
  guid: string
  ``type``: string
  name: string
  version: string
}
```

Then assuming you can get the strings out of the JSON:

```
let strings =
  ["/publication/a40a5e5c-98b3-45ae-d6a3-924b31d8712a/article/test;version=1521246543034";
   "/publication/a40a5e5c-98b3-45ae-d6a3-924b31d8712a/book/test2;version=1520623346891";
   "/publication/a40a5e5c-98b3-45ae-d6a3-924b31d8712a/catalog/test3;version=1520623346833"]
```

You can use a `Regex` to pull the substrings out:

```
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
let regex = new Regex("(([a-f0-9]+\-)+[a-f0-9]+)\/(.*?)\/(.*?);version=(\d*)")
let matchEntity (m: Match) =
  {guid = m.Groups.[1].Value; ``type``= m.Groups.[2].Value; name = m.Groups.[3].Value; version = m.Groups.[4].Value}
```

Then `map` over the inputs, matching each one:

```
strings |> List.map (regex.Match >> matchEntity)

val it : Entity list =
  [{guid = "a40a5e5c-98b3-45ae-d6a3-924b31d8712a";
    type = "d6a3-";
    name = "article";
    version = "test";};
   {guid = "a40a5e5c-98b3-45ae-d6a3-924b31d8712a";
    type = "d6a3-";
    name = "book";
    version = "test2";};
   {guid = "a40a5e5c-98b3-45ae-d6a3-924b31d8712a";
    type = "d6a3-";
    name = "catalog";
    version = "test3";}]
```

Comment: `Then assuming you can get the strings out of the JSON:` that's where I'm stuck, like how to convert json string into array, step about json into string array is what I can't get my head wrap around

Comment: I think I've to use regular expressions to extract strings from JSON, right?

Comment: please review my Edit-attempt for json into array strings, `error FS0010: Unexpected identifier in pattern matching. Expected '->' or other token.`

Comment: there's a bit of problem in your solution, I've list of objects and not strings, I've been working all day on parsing it and it's urgent, This line has a problem `List.map (regex.Match >> matchEntity)`, 1, It perhaps needs to work with `Array.iter`, 2. `matchEntity` is showing squiggly lines saying Type mismatch - expecting `Match->unit` but given `Match->Entity`, I've added some more code for more development I did on this today

Comment: I've also fixed match group indexes

Comment: I've been held back on this for long, appreciate if you can please help me out in here

Comment: `strings |> List.map (regex.Match >> matchEntity)` this line needs revision, the `list[]` has to pipe through instead of `string[]`